# How to decode a json object within a class

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON object which looks like it is wrapped in a class coming in from a handler

```
async def on_status(StatusV2):
  print(StatusV2)
```

It prints an object that looks like this:

```
StatusV2({ 'reason_code': '',
     'reason_message': '',
     'status_code': 'E',
     'status_message': 'Short Sale Restriction',
     'symbol': 'TECL',
     'tape': 'B',
     'timestamp': 1664473992260486912})
```

What I am trying to do is assign variables to certain pieces of this object but have continued to fail at doing so.

For instance, I want variables for status_symbol or status_message so I did:

```
status_symbol=StatusV2.symbol
status_message=StatusV2.status_message
```

However any way I have tried to work with this object I have failed.

Comment: JSON is typically decoded into a dictionary. Have you tried `StatusV2[“symbol”]`?

Comment: @dirn You've got curly quotes in there. It should be `StatusV2["symbol"]`

Comment: Are you sure it's JSON? Vanilla JSON doesn't use single-quotes, only double-quotes.

Comment: Have tried that but no results

Comment: I am not entirely sure thats why the response being StatusV2({ has thrown me off and not sure how to handle it

Comment: @wjandrea that’s what I get for using my phone.

Comment: @FirmCEO we’re going to need to know more about `StatusV2`. We can’t tell you how to access its data without knowing what it is.